# Turning off LESS.js stylesheet auto-compiling

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm trying to use the in-browser copy of LESS.js for compiling code manually through scripting via `less.render`. By default, LESS.js will automatically search for all stylesheets labelled with `rel="stylesheet/less"` and compile them as well.

As I'm only using it to manually compile less code, how do I best turn this off?

In addition, as I don't need the feature at all whatsoever, is there any way of just getting a copy of LESS.js that cuts this feature completely?

Comment: *how do I best turn this off* - you can't. The browser-side version of the Less compiler is not considered (for a few years by now) as something meant for a production (thus initial traversing through link tags is not considered to be worth a dedicated option).

Comment: *a copy of LESS.js that cuts this feature completely* - No such copy exists. So if it's really important I'm afraid you'll have to build your own (either by modifying the "browser" leaf of the code-base or build a browser adopted script from "node" leaf using dedicated tools (like "browserify" or so)).

Comment: Sweet! Thx. If it doesn't exist, I'm fine building it myself - I thought there was, though, as I've seen online examples such as https://lesstester.com/ - it does appear they're using a version for node. Is this done via browserify then? - p.s. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.